# Vagrant vmware error code 7?

Tags: django, vagrant, osx-yosemite, vmware

I'm using Vagrant and it was working perfectly yesterday. I didn't change anything that I'm aware of.

I get this error when trying to `vagrant up`; the error occurs on multiple projects.

My `vagrant plugin list` is:

```
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-vmware-fusion (4.0.1)
```

I'm running OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `vagrant-vmware-fusion` plugin is outdated . Try running `vagrant plugin update` before `vagrant up` again.